# how can we print empty lua array

Tags: lua, lua-table

i want the output something like (an empty array)

```
[]
```

I tried all these below ways , but i wasn't successful in getting the above output

- `ext_const.cjson_encode(setmetatable(ext_const.cjson_decode("{}"), ext_const.array))`
- `ext_const.cjson_encode(ext_const.cjson_decode("[]"))`
- `ext_const.cjson_encode(setmetatable(ext_const.cjson_encode("{}")))`

Comment: This is an interesting question because Lua doesn't have the concept of an array so cjson needs some kind of annotation for which JSON concepts of an empty array and an object with no properties is intended. Please repost your answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

try like this , it should work ..

```
local json = require "json"

local t = {}

local t1 = {name = 1  , name2 = 2}

print(json.encode(t))

print(json.encode(t1))
```

output ,

```
[]
{"name":1,"name2":2}
```

Comment: Nope !! it still returns me "{}"

Comment: is there something called json package .. I see there is only cjson!!